# Based loops objects in model categories

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, simplicial-stuff, model-categories

If I have a pointed model category then for I can define based loops objects as homotopy pullbacks:

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    \Omega X @>>> *\\
    @V  V V @VV  V\\
    * @>>> X
\end{CD}

If my category is additionally powered by simplicial sets, how can I realize iterated loop objects through maps from spheres? I guess this has to be straightforward but I cannot see why it works.

Comment: This ultimately boils down to your preferred definition of spheres. Let S^0 denote ∆^0 with a disjoint basepoint. If one defines S^1 to be the homotopy pushout in simplicial sets of the diagram * <- S^0 -> *, then you basically need to show that S^1 smashed with itself n times is the same as your favorite model for an n-sphere.